# Normal Distribution Stats percentage

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

I already know the answer of the following question, but not able to figure out how it's done. If someone can tell me it would be highly appreciated.

"The owner of a fish market determined that the average weight for a catfish is 3.2 pounds with a standard deviation of 0.8 pound. A citation catfish should be one of the top 2% in weight. Assuming the weights of catfish are normally distributed, at what weight (in pounds) should the citation designation be established?"

The correct answer is 4.84 pounds

Comment: You're looking to find $x$ satisfying $P(X>x)=0.98$, where $X$ is normal distributed with mean $3.2$ and $0.8$. Keywords: quantile, percentile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a TI calculator? Then the answer should be $invnorm(0.98, 3.2, 0.8)$. The syntax for invnorm is (area to the left, mean, std deviation). Since area to the right is 2%, then area to the left is 1-2% = .98

Comment: I don't have a TI calculator, but I do have Excel. Any easy way tih Excel?

Comment: Yep. NORMINV is the function in Excel, with the exact same syntax.

Comment: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/norminv-HP005209193.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The owner of a fish market determined that the mean weight for a catfish is 3.2 pounds with a standard deviation of
0.8 pound. Assuming the weights of catfish are normally distributed, the probability that a randomly selected catfish
will weigh more than 4.4 pounds is _______?

how to calculate ?

Comment: Is this an answer to the OP?